# Curl request gives missing parameter error in php, but it works in the terminal

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to request my access token to test the Indeed Api, running this in my bash terminal works just fine, it gives me the access token:

```sh
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
  -d 'client_id=<my client id>' \
  -d 'client_secret=<my client secret>' \
  https://apis.indeed.com/oauth/v2/tokens
```

But in my php application it doesn't, this is how I built my request function with curl:

```php
function http($url, $data, $headers) {
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  return $result;
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```php
$indeed_api = 'https://apis.indeed.com/oauth/v2/tokens';
$indeed_secrets = [
  "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
  "client_id" => "<my client id>",
  "client_secret" => "<my client secret>"
]; 
$headers = [
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Accept: application/json'
];

$token = http(
  $indeed_api, 
  $indeed_secrets,
  $headers
);

print_r($token);
```

But I get this error:

```json
{
  "error_description": "Invalid request - Missing \"grant_type\" parameter.",
  "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

And as you can see I'm including the `grant_type` with the `client_credentials` value which is the required to get the access token.

Comment: first `http` function that you are calling is having 4 parameters while definition of the function has only three.

Comment: Second `$indeed_secrets` should be associative array
eg. `'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'`

Comment: Third if you are sending it as json encoded format then it should have header of `'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: the function arguments was my bad, I was editing my code to omit non relevant parts and that was a typo, I fixed the array syntax and the content type part but the issue still persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API accepts a form body, so the `CURL_POSTFIELDS` option must be set to a valid query string. You need to pass your array to `http_build_query` before setting the option, like so:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

By passing an array instead, the `Content-Type` header will be automatically set to `multipart/form-data`, which is not what the API expects.

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation.
> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like
> 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key
> and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header
> will be set to multipart/form-data. Files can be sent using CURLFile
> or CURLStringFile, in which case value must be an array.